# How to My own textField and add a redirection method in it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am having a situation where I have to create a a subclass of textField so that when object to this subclass is used in any viewcontroller and user clicks to it to write something then user will automatically redirected to some other class.

Let me explain with the help of an example :
suppose MyTextField is a subclass if UITextField
when and when object of  MyTextField is created in any ViewController1 and user will try to click on that(object of  MyTextField) the application will automatically redirected to a new view controller.

Please note that I don't want to use the Delegate method of the UITextField in the ViewController1.

Is it possible ?

Please reply if you have any alternate

thank you

Comment: even if u get the event in subclass, u'll HAVE to implement delegate method for REDIRECTION in viewController;

Answer (score 1):

As UITextField is inherited from UIResponder, you can use –canBecomeFirstResponder and -becomeFirstResponder methods in your inherited class.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you may have a need to display some text/placeholder in textfield. When a user click on textfield you are navigating to some other class. If i am correct, then why don't you use a button instead of a UITextfield as you are not interested to call the delegate methods of TextField. You can set some delegates which will handle your actions simply.